# laptop not charging with battery and not starting without battery

Tags: laptop, battery, ac-adapter

Me and my sister have identical laptops.

Whilst i was using my laptop i noticed that the laptop was indicating it was charging however the battery power level was decreasing. So it knew the adapter was connected however was not charging the battery.

I tried unistalling the battery firmware from device manager and restarting with no luck.

i tried starting the laptop without the battery. But it wouldnt start.

I tried the steps above again using my sisters power adapter which still didnt work.

I then put my sisters battery in my laptop using my sisters adapter which also didnt charge however does on my sisters laptop.

I have tried everything i can and i am stuck as to what i can do. From what i have searched it seems my adapter was faulty and shorted something on the motherboard.

Comment: This is difficult for me to understand. It sounds as if your laptop IS NOT booting. Is that true? Does it show any sign of life?

Comment: Yes it does. If i put a charged battery into the laptop it works but it does not charge. Sorry for making it soo difficult to understand. I wanted to give as many details as possible.

Comment: What make/model laptop?It sounds as if your battery is no good. Is it OEM or after-market?

Comment: *"it seems my adapter was faulty"* -- Maybe.  Either your power adapter is faulty or the recharging circuity in your laptop is faulty.  You can safely test the former with a voltmeter or multimeter.  A more risky test is to use your power adapter with your sister's laptop.

Comment: The laptop is an Acer k56ca laptop. and sawdust I thought about it but I can't risk it. The laptop is under a year old but is excellent I would definitely recommend it and would buy it again but I'll have to deeply look into whether this is a recurring problem as I have done extensive research to no avail.

Comment: @Xavierjazz I don't have any suspicions the battery is faulty. I think its a fault with the power jack or as sawdust mentioned the recharging circuit. The only way the laptop works is on a charged battery. it does not power up without the battery. the weird thing is the neither mine nor my sisters adapter charge the battery but the laptop does still react like it would when attached, the light for charging appears and the icon on the task bar changes.

Comment: Sounds like laptop internal power switching circuitry is faulty. Being under a year old I suppose it's under warranty.